# RSS Feed broken

Tags: rss

When I try to access my [RSS Feed](http://www.nkonecny.com/blog/feed/) I am getting this error:

error on line 1 at column 35: Unsupported encoding UTF-5

It was working fine just a couple days ago and I'm not sure what I changed if anything to break it.
Any Ideas?

Comment: What plugins are you running? As @helenhousandi points out below, the RSS feed should be using UTF-8, not UTF-5 ... did you recently install something or change themes?

Comment: the entire site is actually UTF5. And there is a missing quote in the head section of the main site, it states charset=UTF-5"  Something is definitely messed up in there

Comment: I've gone into the header php that contains the rss function but can't find "UTF-8" or "UTF" what line of code should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that this has anything to do with WordPress, but I'm pretty sure it should be `UTF-8`, not `UTF-5`. The first line of your RSS feed reads `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-5"?>`.

**Edit:** Try checking your Reading Settings for the `Encoding for pages and feeds` entry.

Comment: Where do I find the feeds file? I've looked in: wp-feed.php, wp-rss.php, wp-rss2.php, wp-load.php, as well as my header and home files, and this is no mention of "UTF"

Comment: I don't think it's a WordPress core file. I'd look at the Reading Settings page in the admin and check the `Encoding for pages and feeds` entry. This also means I have to eat my words, I guess it does have to do with WordPress :)

Comment: You're a genius!! I was right there set to UTF-5, I simply changed it and voilà, RSS is back online :). I know exactly what I did, I some how got into this page and changed it reading it as UTC-8 (timezone) haha and changed it to mine. Thanks again! I'd up vote but not enough rep :(

Comment: Hey, so long as it isn't a mystery! Glad it's working for you.